# About the union of derived sets.

Tags: general-topology

I know that, if $A$ is a set, and $A'$ is the set of all limit points of $A$ (derived set of $A$), then 
$$
A'\cup B'=(A\cup B)'.
$$
But, 
$$
\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i'\neq \left(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\right)'
$$
with $I$ not finite.

My question is, there are a manner to determine $\left(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\right)'$, for example
$$
\left(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\right)'=\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i'\cup\text{ something else}.
$$

In particular, I want to determine the derived of sets like this
$$
\left\{\frac 1 n+\frac 1 m:n,m\in\mathbb{N}\right\}.
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the following.

The something else can be the complete set $\left(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\right)'$, for instance, when each $A_i$ is a one-point set. But maybe the equality $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i'= \left(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\right)'$ holds provided a family $\{A_i:i\in I\}$ is locally finite.

If we have subsets $A,B$ of a topological group $G$ (for instance, $G=\mathbb R$, $A=B=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb N\}$) then $(A+B)’\subset (A’+B)\cup (A+B’)$, but the equality does not necessarily holds (for instance, put $G=\mathbb R$, $A=\mathbb Z$ and $B=\sqrt{2}\mathbb Z$). But, maybe the equality holds provided one of sets $A, B$ is compact.